# My function in r doesn't work. Do you know why?

Tags: r, function

```
find_value <-function(function_2, x)
  {
  x<-readline(prompt = "Enter a real number ")
  function_2<-readline(prompt="Enter a function")
 x<-as.numeric(x)
 function_2<-as.function(function_2)
 return(function_2(x))
}
```

the function should find the value of a math function for a real number

Comment: Use `match.fun` instead of `as.function`.

Comment: `as.function` doesn't retrieve a function, it tries to convert its argument to a function.  Use `match.fun(function_2)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`as.function` is not working as expected. You could use `get`.

```
find_value <-function(function_2, x) {
  x <- readline(prompt = "Enter a real number ")
  function_2 <- readline(prompt="Enter a function")
  
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  function_2 <- get(function_2, mode = "function")
  
  return(function_2(x))
}
```

Or a better alternativ is `match.fun` as suggested in the comments:

```
find_value <- function(function_2 = NULL, x = NULL) {
  
  if(is.null(x)) x <- readline(prompt = "Enter a real number ")
  if(is.null(function_2)) function_2 <- readline(prompt="Enter a function")
  
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  function_2 <- match.fun(function_2)
  
  return(function_2(x))
}
```

We could further add checks, whether the arguments are supplied, so we can run the function without argument. In this case it will ask us for input, or we supply the args and the function will just return the calculated value.

```r
find_value <-function(function_2 = NULL, x = NULL) {
  
  if(is.null(x)) x <- readline(prompt = "Enter a real number ")
  if(is.null(function_2)) function_2 <- readline(prompt="Enter a function")
  
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  function_2 <- match.fun(function_2)
  
  return(function_2(x))
}

find_value("sqrt", 4)
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

We could also use `rlang::as_function` which supports purrr-like lambda functions as well:

```r
find_value <-function(function_2 = NULL, x = NULL) {
  
  if(is.null(x)) x <- readline(prompt = "Enter a real number ")
  if(is.null(function_2)) function_2 <- readline(prompt="Enter a function")
  
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  function_2 <- rlang::as_function(function_2)
  
  return(function_2(x))
}

find_value(~ .x^2, 4)
#> [1] 16
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>